# Python Selenium - AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'send_Keys'

Tags: python, selenium

I try to close the window, in Google Chrome, but get this error

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_Keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w')
```

but get this error:
`AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'send_Keys'`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to close browser window you ccaan use below :

```
driver.close() – It closes the current browser window

driver.quit() –  closes all the browser windows and ends the WebDriver session as well.
```

To avoid above error you can add below import to your solution:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

Answer (score 1):

You should import the function before using it. Use this before calling send_Keys:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```